# Matching data types in Haskell. Conversion error

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write the function `trade_report :: String -> [Transaction] -> String` which will take an element in a list and return the values associated with the element.

For context in what the Type transaction is:

```
type Transaction = (Char, Int, Int, String, Int) 

test_log :: [Transaction]
test_log = [('B', 100, 1104,  "VTI",  1),
            ('B', 200,   36, "ONEQ",  3),
            ('B',  50, 1223,  "VTI",  5),
            ('S', 150, 1240,  "VTI",  9),
            ('B', 100,  229, "IWRD", 10),
            ('S', 200,   32, "ONEQ", 11), 
            ('S', 100,  210, "IWRD", 12)
            ]
```

Comment: You need to apply `transaction_to_string` to *each* element in the result of `get_trades`, not the list as a whole. (Hint: use `map`.) Then you want to join the list of strings you get as a result into a single string using `"\n"` as a separator. (Hint: use `Data.List.intercalate`, which a normal language would call `join` :) )

Comment: To add to @chepner's comment you'll also have to filter out the transactions that don't satisfy the criteria. you can use the `filter` function for that.
The data flow would look some thing like this: transaction_log -> filter logs that you need -> convert each transaction to string -> intercalate the strings.

Comment: @Apoorv I think that's what `get_trades` is doing.

Comment: I have used the map and filter already. Please refer to the edited code. Apologies for not adding it in initially

Comment: At present, this isn't a question. It just says "I am trying to write this function `trade_report`" (without even really specifying what it does) and gives some auxiliary definitions for context. To help you we need to know what code *you* have written to try to solve this, and what *specifically* (full error messages, etc) isn't working. I can see in the edit history you have removed a lot of material; should some of that come back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_trades` returns a *list* of `Transaction` values. `transaction_to_string` only takes a *single* `Transaction` value. You need to use `map`.

```
> :t transaction_to_string
transaction_to_string :: Transaction -> String
> :t map transaction_to_string
map transaction_to_string :: [Transaction] -> [String]
```

Once you have your list of `String` values, you can join them together with `\n` characters using `Data.List.intercalate`.

```
> import Data.List
> intercalate "\n" ["foo", "bar"]
"foo\nbar"
```

Comment: How would you do this without importing Data.List? How could I write it as a single function for trade_report